# Android checkbox state dont change state after some click on that

Tags: android

In my simple adapater, I want to manage checkboxes on items.

when i click again on checked check box and the state is will be unchecked after check again on that checkbox of state don't change

Logcat:

```
E/checkedState: false
E/checkBoxStates: {09122331743=true}
E/checkedState: true
E/checkBoxStates: {09122331743=false}
E/checkedState: true
E/checkBoxStates: {09122331743=false}
E/checkedState: true
E/checkBoxStates: {09122331743=false}
E/checkedState: true
E/checkBoxStates: {09122331743=false}
E/checkedState: true
E/checkBoxStates: {09122331743=false}
E/checkedState: true
E/checkBoxStates: {09122331743=false}
```

my code is:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final CustomContactsViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    ...
    Boolean checkedState = checkBoxStates.get(list.get(position).getMobileNumber());
    holder.select_contact.setChecked(checkedState == null ? false : checkedState);
    holder.select_contact.setTag(position);
    holder.select_contact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onChange((Integer) v.getTag());
        }
    });
}

private void onChange(int position) {
    final UserPhoneContacts item = list.get(position);
    if (item == null) {
        return;
    }

    boolean checkedState = checkBoxStates.get(list.get(position).getMobileNumber()) == null ? false : true;
    Log.e("checkedState ", checkedState + "");

    checkBoxStates.put(item.getMobileNumber(), !checkedState);
    Log.e("checkBoxStates ", checkBoxStates.toString());

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

after click on checkbox, state will be checked and after click on that if state is unchecked, i can't change state after click,

click-> **checked**, click->**unchecked**, click->**unchecked**, click->**unchecked**, click->**unchecked**

how can i resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using holder.select_contact.setOnCheckedChangeListener() instead of onClickListener.

Comment: `setOnCheckedChangeListener` called on every scrolling list

Comment: Then I suggest to redesign your listview to use listview.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE) this is better way to handle checking in listview and you don't have to use this map. Instead you will be able to use SparseBooleanArray containing checked items.